# Skewed Sex Ratios

Tags: biology, evolution, fantasy-races

What factors could skew the sex ratio of an intelligent species, especially a humanoid/human sub-race? For example, say one race has markedly more females born than males, and another race has the opposite, many more males than females. The race is unimportant, whether elves and dwarves, nymphs and goblins, respectively, etc.

What would lead to such scenario when births of one sex are so much more common than births of the other, assuming the parents aren't deliberately altering the ratio somehow?

Comment: Intelligence does not matter. What matters is the [sex determination mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex-determination_system). For example, in many reptiles sex is determined by the temperature at which the eggs develop; there is a species of turtles, the green sea turtle ([*Chelonia midas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_sea_turtle)), which uses this mechanism for sex determination, and, as a consequence of climate warming, is being confronted with [an *extremely* skewed sex ratio](https://qz.com/1176003/green-sea-turtles-are-turning-all-female-due-to-climate-change/).

Comment: And, please, you don't want "gender ratio" (which is meaningless), you want "[sex ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_ratio)". "Gender" is a *social* attribute; it controls whether a person is to be addressed as *Madame* or *Monsieur*, whether they wear skirts or trousers, whether they keep their hair long or short. The biological attribute is "sex".

Comment: Are you asking for a biological reason or a historical reason? In other words, is this a species that naturally has an imbalance or one that has become imbalanced?

Comment: Fisher's principle is what you want here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_principle TL;DR make one sex require more parental investment.

Comment: @AlexP : that is a modern ideological signaling. Many people still use gender to refer to male or female biology, and sex as the act itself. Just because you along with some people switched over to a recent fad doesn't mean you have to push it down the throat of others.

Comment: @vsz: What? Historically, the word used was almost always "sex", with "gender" being almost exclusively something which happenned in grammar. You know, expressions such as "both sexes", "opposite sex", "fair sex", and so on. I have never encountered phrases like "\*\*opposite gender", "\*\*fair gender". (And as dessert, both words are Latin; I have no idea how the English referred to those concepts before learning Latin.) And the use of the phrase "having sex" to mean "making love" is exceedingly modern, being a 20th century innovation.

Comment: @vsz Not just ideological signalling. Those are terms with very precise scientific meanings. In fact if you dig into it you get even more precise terms for Chromosomal sex, the sex a person was born as, the sex they developed into, the gender they identify as, the gender others identify them as etc etc etc. Saying those terms are modern ideological fads could be construed as similar to calling terms from quantum physics ‘that modern mumbo jumbo’. You’re not necessarily wrong, but you’re also not being helpful.

Comment: @AlexP I think that what vsz is getting at is not how scientifically or gramatically the words are used, but how the word is used by Preg-fan in the context of his question. You knew it was about the type of sex these people were. Or in a way that I hear it described: what gender they are. The message that is conveyed is more important than its meaning. Also I wouldnt mind gender to become synonymous to what sex something is. Languages evolve, and there's nothing bad about this change that I can see.

Comment: @Demigan: My original comment (one year ago) was simply a notice that the standard phrase is "sex ratio" and not "gender ratio" as it was originally in the question. The point was that all relevant literature, including for example Wikipedia, calls it "sex ratio", and searching for "gender ratio" would be less useful. No further implications were intended; and the comment was indeed accepted and the question edited. I couldn't care less about what the English word for "sex" is; it's not my mother tongue or everyday language, and I have no affective relation to it.

Comment: @JoeBloggs : I wouldn't compare it to quantum physics. They have experimental verification or at least rigorous mathematical modelling to back up their claims. I try to keep an open mind so I searched myself for what the "gender studies" field published, I've read some publications, took a look at lecture notes and other course material, and I had to realize that they are not studying anything, they are just making statements, making up new terms, there is no discussion or fair debate either: anyone who disagrees is simply labeled evil. Even Catholic theology is much more scientific than that.

Comment: @vsz You’ve clearly read vastly different literature to me then. I’ll agree a lot of people use these terms in the way that you’re railing against. The point I’m trying to make is that in the field of gender science (as a subset of either sociology or biology depending on where you come from) those are specifically precise terms exactly to avoid the kind of knee-jerk reactions that are on display here. You can’t have a meaningful conversation about the differences between sex and gender without defining those terms.

Comment: @vsz to explain why I said quantum mechanics: In QM there is the concept of spin. The definition of spin has nothing to do with the usual usage of the word spin (except maybe very tangentially) but it has a precise scientific meaning. To say that using the word spin in a QM context is wrong because it doesn’t match the usual usage of the word spin is correct (if you use a different context ‘particle spin’ doesn’t make any sense) but not actually helpful.

Comment: @JoeBloggs : Thanks for the clarification, I think I now understand your example. It was not about comparing the seriousness of those two fields, but it was merely about how different fields might use certain terms differently. (but at least quantum physicists aren't lobbying governments to criminalize some of the uses of the word "spin")

Comment: @vsz Yep that was my point. I think most people who treat gender science as a science rather than abusing it to score ideological points hate the idea of lobbying to criminalise words. But hey, I can’t speak for everyone.

Answer (score 14):

**Disease linked to sex chromosome.**

Here is how to do achieve this using the chromosomal system humans use.
Humans determine sex with chromosomes: males are XY and females XX.  There are diseases transmitted on the X chromosomes which mostly affect boys.  An example is [chronic granulomatous disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronic_granulomatous_disease).
[image: x linked disease]
http://disorders.eyes.arizona.edu/disorders/nystagmus-1-congenital-x-linked

If a boy is born with the mutation on his single X chromosome, his immune system will be crippled.  A girl, however, has another X which can rescue her immune system with the normal gene.  This girl will, however, be a carrier - any boy she conceives will have a 50% chance of getting the X with the mutation.  A girl born with 2 X chromosomes both with the mutation will be affected but this implies that her father lived to reproductive age despite having the disease.

If you make this a disease that is lethal in utero, the 50% of males conceived who get a bad X will miscarry.  So assuming that the ratio is 50/50 normally, this would produce a ratio of 75 females to 25 males; half the males die.

---

The converse would be a disease on the X chromosome that involved dose - for example, a mutant gene that made some product that was detrimental in high doses.  To make it work the mutant gene product could increase reproductive fitness in moderate doses - the heterozygote state.  For example, a gene on the X which led to greater fierceness or wakefulness or strength.  Male goblins (XY) who have a mutant X would dominate the smaller goblins, and sire more of the children.  The mutant X would spread through the population.  Mothers with 1 mutant X would likewise be robust and get more than their share of resources.  But if the mother had one mutant X and one normal, and conceived a baby goblin with a mutant X father, any double mutant X female conceived would have too much, and die in utero.  The same scenario as the male one above 75% males and 25% females because double mutant X females die.

[Sickle cell disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sickle-cell_disease#Genetics) works this way (although is not transmitted on the X chromosome).

[image: sickle cell genetics diagram]
A heterozygote individual with one mutant sickle cell gene is resistant to malaria and has a reproductive advantage.  But 2 sickle cell genes (the homozygote) historically led to death in childhood. The fitness advantage of the heterozygote state outweighed the fitness disadvantage when 25% of offspring from 2 her parents die young - so the gene for sickle cell spread through the population.

I am thinking now about the Empress goblin, who is a double mutant x and so much stronger/fiercer than a single mutant x male, and considerably more than a normal goblin.  Since before her birth she has been prevented from dying by constant medication that reduces the effect of the double dose X.

Comment: Case 1 will not work. You cannot have all women to be carriers of this disease: Even if *every* female in a starting population has it only *some daughters* will be carriers. And depending on your reproduction patterns the number of carriers may start dropping over time. For example, women from families known for inability to produce many male heirs will be less desirable brides. Eventually, the sex ratios return to 50/50.

Comment: Case 2 looks plausible but most likely result in three distinct genders associated with biological sex and chromosomes: Male (X*mutant* Y), female (X*mutant* X), and 'neutral' (XY).

Comment: One real-life example of a skewed sex ratio produced by such a genetic mechanism is the [wood lemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_lemming) (_Myopus schisticolor_), which has a sex ratio of about 3:1. They have a mutant X\* chromosome that both overrides the effect of the Y chromosome (causing X\*Y lemmings to be physically female) and has [meiotic drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiotic_drive) in such X\*Y females (causing them to only produce X\* ova). So the population consists of XY males and XX, X\*X and X\*Y females, the latter giving birth only to (X\*X or X\*Y) daughters.

Answer (score 9):

It might seem like chromosomal sex determination would result in a 50/50 sex ratio (at least, at conception--sex-linked differences in survivability may skew that ratio even before birth, as outlined in Will's answer).

Nevertheless, the *human* primary sex ratio (at conception) is just *ever so slightly* tilted towards females... and then switches by birth, to an excess of approximately 7 males for every 100 hundred females. Since males post-birth have higher mortality rates and lower life expectancies than females, it has long been thought that this difference is an evolutionary response to ensure that the sex ratio around reproductive maturity *is* close to 50/50. But whatever the reason, it's clear that just having chromosomal sex determination in humans *isn't good enough*, by itself, to ensure a 50/50 split. Yes, it helps to start there (where other determination systems may *not*), but there are clearly other mechanisms at play, and there's no reason those mechanisms couldn't force any other arbitrary ratio, if there's a good reason for it.

So, you don't need to worry about the underlying fundamental biological sex determination mechanism, or chromosomal structure, or any of that. What you do need to worry about is

a) Factors that would provide an evolutionary pressure towards skewed ratios, by whatever biological mechanism;

b) Over what sub-population you are measuring the ratio. Do you want skewed ratios over the entire population, regardless of age? Do you want consistently skewed ratios across all age groups? Do you want skewed ratios for some specific age groups? Each of these options may be selected for entirely different reasons!

Since the question mentions more males being *born* vs. females, or vice-versa, I'll presume you don't actually care that much about total population figures, or ratios at other specific ages. In that case, the obvious pressures would be extreme mortality for one gender over the other; if, for example, men die at a *much* higher rate that women, for innate (e.g., genetic health) or social (e.g., war) reasons, but the species is generally (serially) monogamous, you'd expect to see a lot more boys born. But if, say, women have extremely high rates of mortality in childbirth, you'd expect the opposite--most babies would need to be girls, to make up for the ones who die early.

Comment: Human sex ratio at birth favors boys over girls weakly, about 1.06 to 1. Then various factors come into play and for people over 65 years of age the sex ratio strongly favors women, about 0.7 men for 1 woman in western countries.

Comment: Eh, 1.07 vs. 1.06... close enough. The point is still valid. Sex ratios at birth are not fixed by the nature of chromosomal sex determination.

Comment: The comment was in support of the answer. The point is that sex ratio at birth and sex ratio later in life are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 7):

China is slanted heavily male because of the One-Child Policy that was in effect for so long. Russia is heavily female because of the shortened lifespan of men, generally attributed to alcoholism. There are so many varieties of ways to create gender-imbalance, it is hard to recommend one without more limits on your problem. For example, the China imbalance affects breeding-age population; the Russia imbalance does not.

What you need is some cultural activity that is gender-specific and life-threatening. Something like toxic makeup/tattoo work, or perilous hunting trips, or a fatal rite-of-passage, to list a few examples. Try to identify why the sexes in your society are divided and then identify a dangerous activity that sits on only one side of that divide.

Answer (score 5):

[Sequential Hermaphroditism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_hermaphroditism) is a trait that occurs in many fish, gastropods or plants, by which their sex changes at a certain age, size, or social rank.

Protandry means all offspring are born male, but some later become female.  For example, a group of [clownfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphiprioninae) has one female, at the top of the social ladder.  When this female dies, the dominant male then changes sex to become female.

Protogyny (which is the more common form) is where all offspring are born female, but some later become male.  A [California sheephead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_sheephead) will change from female to male once it reaches a certain size.

So, *all* offspring of your species are born one gender.  At some point in their life, they may reach a trigger condition that causes them to swap to the other gender.  The skew then comes from *what* that trigger is - there are far more adults over 20 than people under 20 in the world.  There are far more people at the bottom of the social pyramid than at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Have chromosome triplets. Where one of three chromosomes being an X chromosome is enough to make a newborn a genetic female but to be a genetic male it needs two of three chromosomes to be Y chromosomes.

Comment: Triploid is tough but tetraploid can work well and can be adjusted for any desired gender ratio.

Answer (score 3):

These are great answers, but I was getting a different take on the question. Biology has lots of ways to generate such differences. I am going to look at factors that would put pressures on an entire species to skew without eliminating individuals.

- reproductive advantage- the rate limiting step in population growth is how many females you have. I've bred mice, and you need one selected male and dozens of females. I imagine androgynous elves where reproductive rates might be slow and you need to maximize the number of females to repopulate. You could have all of a species born female, and only the rulers transition to male. In certain social fish, if the dominant male dies the alpha female becomes male an takes on the role.
- environmental crisis-locusts undergo a radical transformation to environmental deprivation. Envision an orc-like race where bad conditions cause females to give birth to only males, or even hyper-males (think ogre-orcs). The large number of males lead to invasions of nearby territories and the extermination of the local males in favor of the invaders. The stressed orc genes spread & survive. In humans, there are sociology studies suggesting increased percentages of males in a population leads to increased likelihood of wars (this is admittedly actively debated). And there are genetic studies showing human migrations into populated areas where a preexisting population's genes are incorporated into the subsequent population, but the Y chromosomes disappear.  Kill all the males and there's no competition.
- Obligate parthenogenesis - There are species of reptile where at some point all the males died and only females are left.Evolutionarily there are long-term consequences, but short-term this maximizes the ability to exploit favorable environments by maximizing reproduction. You could require mating with related species to 'catalyze' the process if desired. There could be some kind of genetic transfer (imagine a CRISPR-like arrangement where the child gets a sample of paternal DNA and acquires the same hair/eye color)

Answer (score 3):

### The process is already there, you just need the right evolutionary pressures

A lot of fancy answers about chromosomes etc overlook the fundamental fact that a species can make or reject sperm in ratios of whatever is needed.  An interesting thing about humans for example is that we use hormones to naturally increases/decrease the male to female ratios of births to maintain about a 50:50 split even following things like wars where a lot of men die which should result in severe gender inequalities.

A 50:50 split is an important ratio for a species that evolved to take advantage of monogamous relationships because it maximizes your breeding potential; however, this is not the only survival strategy that works. A species that has evolves to have harems of females coupled with a low birth rate per female may naturally produce less males.  Another case where you have less males is when a "queen" can super breed.  There are genetic advantages to the X chromosome due to extra redundancies that make a mostly female species advantageous when breeding is done only by a select few members of society (like ants or bees). In contrast many species (particularly mammals) tend to have secondary characteristics associated with the Y chromosome which can lead to a physically stronger mostly male population which could also in theory be advantageous when you have a breeding queen scenario.

Answer (score 1):

## The setting's gods deliberately created them that way.

A simple answer is that when the gods of this world were creating it, they decided to create a particular race (or multiple races) with an imbalanced gender ratio.

Why they might choose to do so is an open question - maybe they've got an ideological reason to do so like a combative god wanting an all-male race of goblins to continually fight other races to abduct their women for breeding. Maybe they're an ascended mortal from another world and want to give the men of this new world each the harem of women they would've wanted as a mortal man. Maybe they just think it'd be a neat social experiment. Who is going to argue with them over it, aside from perhaps other gods?

Comment: The race can be *created* this way, but unless there's some pressure that forces them to *stay* that way, they won't, so this solution isn't appropriate for a species that's been around for many generations. Even if humans sprang onto the planet with a major sex imbalance, it would equalize over time due to the fact that biological and evolutionary pressures are pretty similar between the sexes.

Answer (score 1):

## All you need is a Biological Mechanism to make gender transmissible and an Evolutionary Pressure to cause the skew  OR just an Environmental Factor that impacts gender

Human males already have an impact on the sex ratio of their children. Some men carry genes that predispose them to daughters or sons - [https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/12/081211121835.htm.](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/12/081211121835.htm) (some men have more X sperm than Y sperm, others more Y than X and some equal amounts). All you need is a reason for one genetic variant to be more advantageous than the other to end up with a large sex ratio skew. Say almost all the men are killed in continual wars, then "Bob" who managed to survive and has a predisoposition to having sons will have loads of grandchildren because all his sons will father many kids because there are so many women available, while "Tim" who survived the war has a predisposition to having daughters none of whom can find husbands so he has no grandchildren to pass his "daughter" genes to. You eventually get a population that skews heavily to producing Y chromosomes, and therefor baby boys. There are many other reasons why sex ratios are likely to skew at birth - though in most species they settle around 50% because anytime there are only a handful of sex "A" they are guaranteed to find mates while sex "B" is not, so sex "A" passes on their genes at a higher frequency including the genes that made them sex "A" - this happens until the ratios even out.

You could also have the sex ratios dependent on the environment (for example a lot of reptile species have sex dependent on temperature) maybe there were certain temperatures that the species evolved with (that resulted in 50/50 sex ratios) but now the temperature has shifted so that there are way more males than females. There is already concern that some species may start to struggle due to climate change.

Answer (score 0):

https://bigislandbees.com/blogs/bee-blog/14137353-bee-hive-hierarchy-and-activities

Look at bees dude, they have way more females than males. I would assume it has to how specialized the drones are meant for breeding while the females don't actually have to bear any children except for the queen.

Comment: [The details of bee reproduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(bee)) are actually a lot more interesting than this answer or the article it links to do it justice. But the gist of it is that unfertilized bee eggs become drones while fertilized bee eggs become workers or queens. Also, drones only have half as much DNA as workers/queens. Calling one male and the other female might in fact be misleading, because there are no such things as X and Y chromosomes in bees. Genetically speaking, bee reproduction works completely different than vertebrate reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

> What factors could skew the sex ratio of an intelligent species (...)

The species as a whole is intelligent, but one of the genders is not. This happens in the real world, for example, with humans.

As anedoctal evidence, the ratio of men to women in the cast of Jackass tends to infinity:zero.

That is a poor sample group, though, so I did some further research. Statistics show that [for every man that wins a Darwin Award, approximately 0.127 women are similarly awarded](https://www.bmj.com/content/349/bmj.g7094). And this is why there are more women than men alive at any moment - males are more prone to engage in idiotic behaviour, which causes them to die stupidly more often.

Comment: Your Darwin Award statistic is off by a factor of 100. That link analyzes 282 male DA winners and 36 female DA winners, for a ratio of less than 10:1, not 1000:1. They also for some reason omit cases that involved both a man and a woman, which would put the ratio closer to 5:1. And let's not forget that males' genetic material is a lot more dangly and vulnerable than females', so equally stupid behavior between the sexes would likely still result in an imbalance in DA winners.

Comment: @NuclearWang ok, I will edit my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward mechanism for hominids is that multiple births are much more common for one sex than the other. For instance, if males were (almost) always singles but females were (almost) always twins or triplets, or vice versa, a significant imbalance is inevitable. We know there's a genetic component to multiples, so all you need is a mutation that makes it somehow sex-linked. Or maybe your species originally always had multiples (like armadillos) and the mutation was having singles for one sex.

If a society *wants* more of a given sex, then those who have multiples of that sex (and not of the other) would be prized mates and their mutation would rapidly spread. It just happens in your story that one race prizes male children and the other prizes female children, so you can easily evolve opposite results.

This could relate to other differences in their societies. For instance, long-lived elves might prefer fewer females to limit population growth, whereas short-lived orcs might prefer more females so they can continually replace warriors lost in battle. Or maybe the sex imbalance is what *caused* elves to be peaceful and orcs to be warlike. Cause and effect can be tricky.